# Why was Palm sent on the mission to see the king and his guards?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I'm not sure of the etiquette of this site so I'm just going to point out at the beginning here that this post will have spoilers. I'll edit this part out if I am informed that spoiler warnings are unnecessary.

In episode 107, Palm is caught by Pitou's En while on a mission to infiltrate the castle and catch a glimpse of the king and his guards. Her power makes the tactical advantage of accomplishing this mission obvious, but it doesn't make much sense from a planning perspective.

The Hunter association was aware of Pitou's ability to detect intruders at tremendous distances. They also knew that this ability was in use around the castle; evidence being that Knov's comment about the En barrier being unexpectedly lowered, thus allowing him to place portals in the castle.

With this in mind, it seems that there would be zero chance of Palm succeeding in her mission; at best she is made useless by being trapped in the underground compound, and at worst she is captured. The fact that they chose to send her on this mission is baffling to me because the characters in the show usually engage in an extremely detailed risk analysis for important decisions.

The only thing I can think of that would make sense from a planning perspective is that they cynically counted on the team's sympathy for Palm to get them fired up for battle when they discover she has been captured. In other words, a sort of artificial morale booster.

Can someone provide a plausible in-world justification for this mission?

Comment: Note: if you want to mark something as a spoiler, type ">!" before the appropriate paragraph.  This does have issues if there are more than one paragraph in a row.

Comment: @kaine That can be dealt with by adding >! before every new paragraph

Comment: @AshishGupta If I do that or if someone else does that, the ">" is acknowledged and the "!" is read as text.  I dont think it is just my browser as I've seen it at work (IE) and home (Chrome).  I fix that by putting any unspoiler text between the separate paragraphs.  This is a little off topic though.

Comment: When I have time and able to get to a computer I'll throw out and answer

Answer (score 4):

[Palm](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Palm_Siberia) was sent into the compound with some other women to serve as a secretary to [Director Bizeff](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Bizeff). This as we all know is a farce the idea is that Palm will try to infiltrate the compound further to gain knowledge on the Royal Guard and the [King](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Meruem). If you remember that she is an [Enhancement Nen](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Enhancer) user and contains Clairvoyance that pre-ant transformation she could:

> Palm is a clairvoyant. Her ability requires her to feed her own blood to a dried merman corpse carrying a crystal ball. After fulfilling this condition, Palm becomes able to track the location of anyone she has seen with her own eyes.

She was attempting to just catch a glimpse of the King so that she could track him. In a covert operation any information that can be gained can drastically change the outcome. Up to this point no has had any information on the two royal guards and king besides what [Colt](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Colt) possibly told them. It may seem illogical to most people but if there is even a chance to gain the upper hand against a powerful opponent most people will take it. We also need to remember that she is a hunter and every hunter knows that going into a job doesn't necessarily mean they will come out alive.

Just imagine if she was able to relay information to the others on the location of the King. Would [Komugi](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Komugi) have been hurt by the Dragon Dive? Maybe the operation would have changed and they would have bypassed the Royal Guard and ambushed the King directly.

TL:DR - Was basically just a grab for information.

Answer (score 0):

They screwed up the continuity there a bit. Palm rode the elevator up using Bizeff's code but later they say if someone enters a code that doesn't match the height and weight of who it belonged to then it locks down.